# How to read unicode filename in python?

Tags: python, windows, unicode

I saw lot and lot of forums about unicode, utf-8 but unable to do this.
I am using `Windows`.

Let's have two folder:

```
E:\old
---- திருக்குறள்.txt
---- many more unicode named files

E:\new
----
```

Language : Tamil

Assume I want to move file to E:\new. I cannot access unicode filename properly.

**What I Tried**

```
import sys
import os
from shutil import copyfile

path = 'E:/old/'
for root, _, files in os.walk(ur''.join(path)):
    files = [f for f in files]
    copyfile(files[0].encode('utf-8').strip(),'E:/new/')   //just for example
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 8, in <module>
    copyfile(files[0].encode('utf-8').strip(),'E:/new/')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\xe0\xae\xa4\xe0\xae\xbf\xe0\xae\xb0\xe0\xaf\x81\xe0\xae\x95\xe0\xaf\x8d\xe0\xae\x95\xe0\xaf\x81\xe0\xae\xb1\xe0\xae\xb3\xe0\xaf\x8d.txt'
```

Comment: I believe you just need to pass the path as a unicode-string (change to `path = u'E:\old'`) ... I ran into the same problem a while ago and I think that solved it. (Am not on a Windows-machine right now, can't verify)

Comment: but for some reasons, i want to read file one by one. :(

Comment: You don't need the `.encode('utf-8').strip()`, just use `files[0]`, however you **do** need to add a `os.path.join()` to construct the full path to the file, which is what should be passed to `copyfile()`.

Comment: Definitely don't encode. When working with Windows paths, stay in Unicode from start to finish. Python 2 isn't perfect here, but the `os` module almost always uses the [W]ide-character Windows APIs for Unicode arguments.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows use Unicode paths.  Since you are using os.walk() you'll need to handle paths correctly to subdirectories, but you could just use `shutil.copytree` instead.  If you don't need subdirectories, use `os.listdir`.

Here's something that works with `os.walk`:

```
import os
import shutil

for path,dirs,files in os.walk(u'old'):
    for filename in files:
        # build the source path
        src = os.path.join(path,filename)
        # build the destination path relative to the source path
        dst = os.path.join('new',os.path.relpath(src,'old'))
        try:
            # ensure the destination directories and subdirectories exist.
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dst))
        except FileExistsError:
            pass
        shutil.copyfile(src,dst)
```